# How do i set a cookie on different node js routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, backend

I'm developing a user based project, using node ( express, mongoose etc. )

I currently use JWT and the token has the user id in it, I know how to send a cookie when someone logs in, but I don't know how to make the cookie work on all routes, like basically when a user is logged in and goes on route /test the cookie is still there.

I think what I'm trying to achieve is called "session/cookie based authentication", could be wrong idk.

Comment: Your server would typically only set the cookie on login/refresh/logout, and the client (web browser) would send the cookie on every request. Your server would have some "middleware" that would read the cookie on each request (or at least those endpoints that require auth)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us your code that tries to set your cookie, and your code that tries to read it. And, look at the Application and Network tabs of your browser devtools, and/or install the Edit This Cookie browser extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you set a cookie, from within any route, with

```
const myCookieValue = 'whatever'
res.cookie('myCookieName', myCookieValue, {
  maxAge: 3600*1000, /* one hour */
  httpOnly: true
})
```

you can retrieve its value, from within any route, with

```
const myCookieValue = req.cookies.myCookieName || 'yo! no cookie! something is wrong!'
```

The `cookie-parser` package makes this possible, handling the gnarliness of the the HTTP header for you.

Comment: that's what im doing, but without the maxage or the httponly, and i tried sooooo many ways to get the req.cookie or req.cookies and its just not working, all ways give me undefined or [Function]

Comment: OK, then we need more information to help you. See my comment under your question.

Comment: fixed it, i needed to console.log(req.headers.cookies) for it to work, pretty weird ngl.